# There are no images open - Fiji/ImageJ macro language

Tags: macros, imagej

I wrote a macro in Fiji to perform a set of operations on all the images in a particular folder. But I ran into trouble and can't get over one problem. I get an error message that says 'There are no images open' when I run the macro. What does it mean? (The images in input folder are of .tif type)

Here's the macro:

```js
input =  "C:"+File.separator+"Winter Quarter slides"+File.separator+"CTIA"+File.separator+"Project"+File.separator+"Original Image data"+File.separator+"Input Images"+File.separator;

output =  "C:"+File.separator+"Winter Quarter slides"+File.separator+"CTIA"+File.separator+"Project"+File.separator+"Original Image data"+File.separator+"Output Images"+File.separator;

setBatchMode(true);
list=getFileList(input);
for(i=0; i<list.length; i++)
    action(input,output,list[i]);
setBatchMode(false);

function action(input,output,filename) {
    open(input+filename);
    run("16-bit");
    run("Gaussian Blur...", "sigma=3");
    setAutoThreshold("Otsu");
    //run("Threshold...");
    setAutoThreshold("Otsu");
    setOption("BlackBackground", false);
    run("Convert to Mask");
    run("Close");
    run("Watershed");
    saveAs("Tiff", output+filename);
    close();
}

close();
```

Can someone please help me out with it asap? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Another thing that would cause this error would be non-image files in the input directory. You loop through all the content in the folder and treat it like an image. If there is for example a text file, the result of `open(input+filename)` will not be an open image.

Comment: I have just image files in the directory, but thanks for the pointer. Will keep in mind the next time!

Answer (score 1):

When several windows are open, the macro commands need definition of which window to work on.

In my micros i use ; selectWindow("imagename"); before the command. This should hopfully solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I've not used the macro language but I have seen that error when developing in Java. Some Plugins require that an image is showing.

If the image isn't showing after `open(input+filename);` then you need to run a show function to display the image.

You do

```
run("Close");
run("Watershed");
saveAs("Tiff", output+filename);
```

So you close the image and then try to do things to the image which would produce that error.

Comment: Hi! Actually, close there closes the autothreshold dialog box and not the image. Image is still open at that point in the code, but the error still remains.

Comment: What about the final close()? Aren't all the images closed by that point so there is nothing to close()?

Comment: Yeah! It works now. I removed the final close. but there still seems to be a problem somewhere. I don't see any error but I can't see the Output files in the output destination. Is this because I removed that close?  where am I going wrong?

Comment: Ok so the same macro runs when I run by batch processing option and for some reason, it is saving the same input images in the output folder!! (I have 90 images in input folder and none in output and when the macro is run, i see the same 90 images that were in input in the output folder too.) Any idea what the problem is?

Comment: File.makeDirectory(output) might be necessary.